# How can I change the color of the active of text in navbar

Tags: typescript

I have 5 links on my navbar and I want to change the color of the text: it should be blue when page is open and gray when another page is open. First page in list is deafult. Also I want change color of the svg, how can I do it? This is my code in TypeScript:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../StyleSheets/navigation.css' ;
import doc from '../Svg/doc.svg'
import documents from '../Svg/documents.svg'
import lk_role from '../Svg/lk-role.svg'
import information from '../Svg/information.svg'
import role from '../Svg/role.svg'

export default function NavBar() {
    return (
        <nav className="navigation">
            <div className="header_text blue">
                Notifications
            </div>
            <div className="navigation_properties">
                <Link to='/notifications-list' className="text_image_block">
                    <img src={doc}></img>
                    <div className="navigation_text gray">Notifications</div>
                </Link>
                <Link to='/create-notification' className="text_image_block">
                    <img src={role}></img>
                    <div className="navigation_text gray">Create notification</div>
                </Link>
                <Link to='/statistics' className="text_image_block">
                    <img src={documents}></img>
                    <div className="navigation_text gray">Statistics</div>
                </Link>
                <Link to='/subscription-management' className="text_image_block">
                    <img src={lk_role}></img>
                    <div className="navigation_text gray">Subscription</div>
                </Link>
                <Link to='/information' className="text_image_block">
                    <img src={information}></img>
                    <div className="navigation_text gray">Information</div>
                </Link>
            </div>
        </nav>
    )
}
```